# How to skip the next iteration in for loop, python?

Tags: python, loops

```
co1=["CM","CD","XC","XL","IX","IV"]
s='AAMCML'

for i,j in enumerate(s):
    if i<len(s)-1 and ((j+s[i+1]) in co1):
        print(j+s[i+1])
        **SKIP NEXT LOOP VALUE (I don't need the next value in loop to be printed. 
                                                               Here it would be M)**
    print(j)
```

I want the result to be printed like [A A M CM L] (it need not be necessarily a list, just print). In this case M after C should not be printed in the output. Any suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: check if the current value is to be skipped and if so then write `continue` which will restart with the next value of the for loop

Comment: That's what `continue` is for. See the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).

Comment: `continue` only skips the current iteration value i.e. C, but not M. If I try continue two times also, it does not work. You can just try running the program with `continue` and let me know, thank you

Comment: @MartijnPieters could you please suggest me the solution for the above comment, it would be very helpful